# R Lubridate Daylight Savings Times appears NA

Tags: r, lubridate

I am working with a dataset that has millions of timestamped records from 1/1/2016 to 8/31/2016. They were read in as characters and I converted them as so:

```
 dt$dropoffDT<-strptime(dt$dropoffDT, format="%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S")
```

They all converted correctly except for records from March 13, 2016 between 2 and 3am. Daylight Savings Time began at 2am on Mach 13th.

These records print as datetimes but seem to be recorded as NA, making it impossible for me to further manipulate the fields. Here is the head and summary for the dataset where I've isolated these records:

```
head(dropDT)
                 dropoffDT
15403  2016-03-13 02:09:45
25304  2016-03-13 02:15:52
314784 2016-03-13 02:01:00
429343 2016-03-13 02:05:25
475529 2016-03-13 02:08:00
503665 2016-03-13 02:00:10

summary(dropDT)
   dropoffDT  
 Min.   :NA   
 1st Qu.:NA   
 Median :NA   
 Mean   :NA   
 3rd Qu.:NA   
 Max.   :NA   
 NA's   :192
```

Your thoughts appreciated. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

The conversion routines have a method for datetimes that are encoded in non-DST bases. Consider using "UCT" (or "GMT") for all your times:

```
as.POSIXct(dt$dropoffDT, format="%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S",  usetz=TRUE, tz="UCT")
```

MCVE:

```
dt <- #  made with dput(dt)
structure(list(dropoffDT = structure(c(1L, 5L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 6L
), .Label = c("2016-03-12 02:09:45", "2016-03-13 02:01:00", "2016-03-13 02:05:25", 
"2016-03-13 02:08:00", "2016-03-13 02:15:52", "2016-03-14 02:00:10"
), class = "factor")), .Names = "dropoffDT", class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-6L))

 as.POSIXct(dt$dropoffDT, format="%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S",  usetz=TRUE, tz="GMT")

[1] "2016-03-12 02:09:45 GMT" "2016-03-13 02:15:52 GMT"
[3] "2016-03-13 02:01:00 GMT" "2016-03-13 02:05:25 GMT"
[5] "2016-03-13 02:08:00 GMT" "2016-03-14 02:00:10 GMT"
```

I only saw the `lubridate` aspect later. I'm not a user of that package. Scanning through the functions with the letters `tz` made me think those functions would need to have the arguments already in a 'datetime'-format.

I find the timezone parameters in R very confusing (and I'm not the only one: [Confused by DateTime offsets](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22056059/confused-by-datetime-offsets) .) That questioner had the correct format to specify a non-DST zone with an offset: the US Pacific stantard zone where I am would be `tz="Etc/GMT+8"`, noting that a plus sign is used despite the fact that our times have hours that would need to be 8 less than London's times.

When I'm working on these aspects I generally need to do testing:

```
 strftime( Sys.time(),  usetz=TRUE, tz="Etc/GMT-7")
#[1] "2016-12-04 23:53:42 GMT-7"
# No, it's not midnight here
 strftime( Sys.time(),  usetz=TRUE, tz="Etc/GMT+7")
#[1] "2016-12-04 09:53:52 GMT+7"

# it's not  9:53A either
 strftime( Sys.time(),  usetz=TRUE)
#[1] "2016-12-04 08:54:13 PST"
 strftime( Sys.time(),  usetz=TRUE, tz="Etc/GMT+8")
#[1] "2016-12-04 08:54:26 GMT+8"
```